# Encouraging/Discouraging flagging

Tags: discussion, flags

*Since I have never been involved in moderation on the Stack Exchange network, I readily admit that my vision is unencumbered by knowledge...*

Assuming I correctly understand its function, flagging is an important tool that helps clean up noise on Stack Overflow and eliminate a slew of low quality/inappropriate content. I also understand that, for moderators, dealing with an overwhelming number of flags can be...overwhelming.

I have recently had a couple of flags declined that I feel were legitimate ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387572/go-to-different-url-on-clicking-button/23183520#23183520)...code-only [wrong] answer).

I have read the [Proper reaction to disputed/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252063/proper-reaction-to-disputed-declined-flags) and I agree with the accepted answer. Re-flagging is not the answer.

**Points for discussion:**

- If re-flagging is not the answer, does/should it stop there?
- Does a declined flag without explanation discourage future flagging...if so, does it matter?
- Should we provide the flagger with more information, similar to how questions are closed? For example, `Your flag was declined because [insert canned response here]`?

Providing additional information on declined flags may, over time, decrease the flagged queue as people learn what flags will be accepted and what flags will be declined.

Comment: Regarding the flag you feel was legitimate, I don't recall some sort of SO rule that code-only answers are forbidden. Did I miss something? They may not be to the level of quality you'd want, and so you can downvote. And a wrong answer is still an answer so it does not warrant action on the part of moderators. Again, downvote is the appropriate action you can take.

Comment: @Louis, I think you're missing the point of my question. The example I gave was just that, an example. The heart of the question involves how to improve the flagging process and the explanation given to the user when a flag is accepted/declined. Having said that, if a code-only response (and a wrong one at that) does not qualify as `very low quality`, nothing does.

Comment: I understood your question but choose to address your views regarding that specific flag.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, declined flags doesn't just discourage from future flagging, it might ban you from doing so...

Comment: I had raised a concern regarding *technically wrong answers*, and most of the response tend to say that *"it is an example for a bad answer, so downvote it and leave it there"*:  it serves as an example for a bad answer.. and i wonder how many could there be..!

Comment: Part of the problem with flags is *timing*. For instance, I flagged a link only answer only to find it declined at a later point. When I went back to the answer it had been edited to include code which had obviously been done before the mod got there. There were comments on the post that indicated that at one point it had been a link only answer. I understand why my flag was declined, but it also left me feeling a bit discouraged. How many declines do you have to have before you cannot flag any more?

Answer (score 10):

> If re-flagging is not the answer, does/should it stop there?

You can always leave a comment to the OP. In fact, you should do that before flagging in most cases.

> Should we provide the flagger with more information, similar to how questions are closed? For example,

If you go to your [flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/763246) on your profile page, you'll see moderator responses to your flags:

[image]

> Does a declined flag without explanation discourage future flagging...if so, does it matter?

You always get a response if your flag is declined. Again, see your profile summary page.
There are two issues at play:

In your example, you flagged an answer wrongly. There are five specific flags on answers:

- This answer is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

Spam: The old fashioned viagra toting, you've won a million dollars from an exiled prince in Nigeria sort of spam.

- it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech

Would a reasonable person find the content of this answer to be offensive, abusive, or hate speech?

- it is not an answer

The Poster forgot what the box was for. They used it instead to try to post a new question, a comment on another post, or they wanted to tell us they liked bananas. I like bananas too.

- it is very low quality

Wall of Garbage.  No reasonable amount of editing will help it. It just needs to be deleted. By a Moderator. Now.

- other (needs ♦ moderator attention)

Tell us what's wrong with the post, why it's wrong, and what we should do about it. Concisely.

In your case, you flagged it as "very low quality".  It is not a "Wall of garbage", and all it needs to be more awesome is a brief description of how the answer better fits the problem presented.  It could stand on its own (though I'd downvote it for lacking completeness), but there's nothing about it that is *very* low quality.

The second issue is that there's an expectation that by the time you get to the point where you're flagging things, you know what you're doing. You've been around the community, you've seen good and bad posts, and you understand the reasons to flag.

If you don't understand the reasons to flag: Don't flag.  Or, if you really feel like something is off but you're not sure what, flag with a reason of "Other" and let us know what, why, and what we should do.

The onus is on the flagger to understand what the descriptions of the flags mean.  We've talked at length about each of these on meta, and the flags have evolved to give the greatest understanding in the fewest amount of words.

If you've got a specific suggestion on how to improve it, we're all ears; however, outside of the years of hammering out we've done to make the flag reasons clear, there's not much else we can do.

If a moderator *chooses to*, they can leave a custom response to a flag (either decline or helpful).  Normally we do not do this; The stock responses cover 90% of all cases. For the other 10%, we'll leave a custom declination response.

Yours was easy; the answer wasn't "Very low quality", so the moderator found no evidence to support your assertion.

Comment: George, thanks for the response, I appreciate it. I readily admit that I misunderstood the purpose of very low quality (the verbiage is pretty misleading, IMHO). I still contend that giving the user more information about a rejection could really help matters. Instructing users to scour meta and read multiple threads, many times expressing different opinions, is certainly something that can be improved upon. In addition, I'm not a fan of the, `If you don't understand the reasons to flag: Don't flag` approach. It discourages community and participation (which is really the point of this post).

Comment: @JamesHill With 2000+ flags in the queue, 16 moderators; and averaging hundreds of flags handled daily; would you rather we handle less flags and take the time to give a custom response to every flag? Or use the custom responses only when they're required?  Also, if you don't know what the flags mean; why would you use them?  If you have ways to help us improve the verbiage, please bring them up.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker This is something that comes up on Meta every once in a while when someone gets annoyed enough:  It's not about not knowing what a flag means, it's that the intent behind the existence of some flags doesn't actually match the name of the flag.

Comment: You seem to be taking this personally. Certainly if you read my initial post you'll see that I wasn't at all suggesting that a personal response be given when flags are rejected. In addition, I acknowledged the burden that flags are on our Mods. My intention was to have a productive discussion about improving the flagging process. Respectfully, your attitude is unbecoming of a moderator. Again, I believe these types of responses go against the very intention of the SE **community**.

Comment: @JamesHill I'm not taking this personally; I'm telling you what the state of the system is.  I don't understand what you're driving at (what discussion do you want to have about 'improving the flagging process'?) Based on the answer I gave, all the points you talk about (except improving the verbiage for 'very low quality') don't have any actual discussion attached as to how we can improve them, or how they're deficient. My comments are to suss out exactly what you think is deficient, because your posts and your comments don't make that clear; they make it seem like you don't get the system.

Comment: @JamesHill If the system is hard to get; let's make it better. That seems to be what you want; but with the points you bring up, they appear to all be covered.

Comment: +1 for liking bananas. *now I want a banana, but do not have one* :(

Comment: "the flags have evolved to give the greatest understanding in the fewest amount of words" → TBH some of these flags would be better sold with *more* words, not less. Especially some people not understanding that "spam" is somewhat specific. I would suggest a link on flag popup box that says "learn more" and expands on what the flags should actually be used for. And, I mean, you say "If you don't understand the reasons to flag: Don't flag." as if everyone new to flagging understood the process. No doubt some people use it more than they should *because they've never been told not to*.

Comment: -1 bananas are awful. :p (Not really. I mean, yes bananas are awful, but I still upvoted.)

Answer (score 3):

George's answer is great.   I'm just picking up on the point that moderators *can* leave a response to a flag.   Therefore, if you didn't get one, chances are it's because the reason for the flag was flat out wrong.   IE rejection of a "low quality post" means "this is not a low quality post".  What more would there be to say?   Maybe "please read the criteria for low quality posts, and if still in doubt go ask at meta" ;)

I'm new to reviewing flags, and let me tell you that people flagging posts as "low quality" when what they mean is "I think this answer is wrong" is an eye opener.    Interestingly, this might be an argument in favour of your point: maybe people would do this less if they got better feedback in the first place.

However, I also learned something else today on this topic: there are system-flags.   The system itself can raise "low quality" flags.   This means that it's kinda pointless giving feedback as you reject it :)   Right now you can't tell who flagged the post, so you can't tell if it's a system one.   That'd have to change, if we're encouraging more feedback about rejected flags.

Comment: Keep in mind "Low quality" and "very low quality" are two different things. I'm not a fan of the the verbiage used because people mix the two up, but there it is.

Comment: Hot dang, I'm going to have to study up on that, too, now!!